# Infinite expected return time implies return probabilities tend to zero

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For a Markov chain $X_n$ I want to prove that if
$$ \mathbb{E} (\min\{n \geq 1:X_n = i\}\mid X_0 = i) = \infty$$
(that is, if $i$ is transient or null recurrent), then
$$ p_{ii}^{(n)} \equiv \mathbb{P}(X_n = i \mid X_0 = i) \to 0 \quad \mathrm{as} \quad n \to \infty .$$
My intuition is that if the above expected value is infinite, then the probability that the first return to $i$ occurs at $n$ must decay relatively slowly with $n$, which means it's 'fairly likely' that the chain won't have returned to $i$ in the first $n$ steps. Hence the return probabilities are small. However, I can't turn this into a proof that they decay to zero. Please be as elementary as possible!

---

If $i$ is transient then the theorem is easy to prove. Transience is equivalent to the sum of the $p_{ii}^{(n)}$ being finite, which means they must tend to zero. The null recurrent case is proving more stubborn.

Comment: Try to show that if $p_{ii}^{(n)}$ does not go to zero then $i$ must be positive recurrent.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, I have been trying and failing to show this. If the $p_{ii}^{(n)}$ don't go to zero, then the probability of the first return occurring at large $n$ is small. I want to argue that this probability decays quickly, because it means that the chain hasn't returned in two steps *and* hasn't returned in three steps *and* hasn't returned in four steps *and* ... But these events aren't independent, so I can't simply construct some kind of exponential decay that would render the expected first return time finite.

Comment: The problem is that you need to use somewhere that $p_{ii}^{(n)}$ is not just an arbitrary sequence of probabilities but actually arises from a Markov chain. Otherwise I think you can put its "spikes back above zero" farther and farther away from each other and then you don't get what you want.

Comment: I remember there was some reasonably simple general relation between $f_{ij}^{(n)}$ (the first passage time probabilities) and $p_{ij}^{(n)}$, but I don't recall what exactly it is. Of course $E[T_{ii}]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left ( 1-\sum_{j=0}^n f_{ii}^{(j)} \right )$, so that is the connection there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one proof that I found in Section 1.8 of James Norris' Markov Chains. It's far more sophisticated than I thought would be necessary; if anybody has a more straightforward proof to offer it would be much appreciated.

Suppose $X_n$ is null recurrent. If it is periodic with period $d$, we can consider the aperiodic subchain $X_{dn}$ and prove that return probabilities for this chain tend to zero, thereby proving that all return probabilities tend to zero. Hence assume the chain is aperiodic.

Let $T_j$ be the first return time to state $j$. We know that
$$ \infty = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty k \,\mathbb{P}_j(T_j = k) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \mathbb{P}_j(T_j > k) \,.$$
Given $\varepsilon > 0$ choose $K$ such that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^K \mathbb{P}_j(T_j > k) \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \,.$$
Then, for $n \geq K$,
$$
\begin{align}1 &\geq \sum_{k =n-K}^n\mathbb{P}(X_k = j, X_m \neq j \;\text{for}\; m=k+1,\ldots,n) \\ 
&= \sum_{k =n-K}^n \mathbb{P}(X_k = j)\mathbb{P}_j(T_j > n - k) \\
&=\sum_{k =0}^K \mathbb{P}(X_{n-k} = j)\mathbb{P}_j(T_j > k)\,.\end{align}$$
Hence we must have $\mathbb{P}_j(X_{n-k} = j)\leq \varepsilon$ for some $k = 0,1,\ldots,K$.

Now we make a coupling argument. Let $Y_n$ be a chain with the same transition probabilities as $X_n$ and an initial distribution to be defined later. The chain $W_n = (X_n,Y_n)$ is irreducible by virtue of the aperiodicity of $X_n$. If $W_n$ is transient then by setting $X_n$ and $Y_n$ to have the same initial distribution we can easily show that return probabilities tend to zero.

So assume that $W_n$ is recurrent. But an *irreducible* recurrent chain explores all states with unit probability, so the two chains $X_n$ and $Y_n$ meet almost surely. Set $Z_n$ to equal $X_n$ before the two chains meet (at $n = T$, say) and $Y_n$ thereafter. Then $X_n$ and $Z_n$ have the same distribution so
$$\begin{align}|\mathbb{P}(X_n = j) - \mathbb{P}(Y_n = j)| &= |\mathbb{P}(Z_n = j) - \mathbb{P}(Y_n = j)| \\
&=|\mathbb{P}(X_n = j, n < T) - \mathbb{P}(Y_n = j, n < T)| \\
& \leq \mathbb{P}(n < T) \to 0 \,.
\end{align} $$
Hence the two chains $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have converging return probabilities. Now we just need to exploit the fact that we are free to choose the initial distribution for $Y_n$. If $X_n$ has initial distribution $\lambda$ let $Y_n$ have initial distribution $\lambda P^k$ for $k = 1,\ldots,K$, so that $\mathbb{P}(Y_n = j) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+k} = j)$. Since the two chains have convergent probabilities, we can find $N$ such that for $n \geq N$ and $k=1,\ldots,K$,
$$ | \mathbb{P}(X_n = j) - \mathbb{P}(X_{n+k} = j)| \leq \varepsilon \,.$$
Finally, we know from before that in any interval of length $K$ there is some $k$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_k = j) \leq \varepsilon$, and hence
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_n = j) \leq 2 \varepsilon \,.$$
Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary we have proved the result.

Comment: Note a very similar coupling argument is used to prove convergence to equilibrium for the aperiodic positive recurrent case (Theorem 1.8.3). It seems like the null recurrent case isn't much simpler than the positive recurrent case.

Comment: @Dap Indeed, it seems that way. The only simplification is that we don't need to prove that $W_n$ is recurrent, since if it's transient the result follows straightforwardly (return probabilities of $W_n$ can be taken to be the square of return probabilities of $X_n$).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof taken from Chapter 3 of Karlin and Taylor's A First Course in Stochastic Processes. It is more elementary but perhaps less illuminating. Let $X_n$ be an aperiodic, null recurrent Markov chain (see other answer for reducing to the aperiodic case). Let $T_j$ be the first return time to state $j$ and define the sequences
$$a_n = \mathbb{P}_j(T_j = n) \quad \text{and} \quad u_n = p_{jj}^{(n)}\,.$$
These satisfy the equation
$$ u_n - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k \,a_{n-k}  = 0 \quad n\geq 1\tag{1}\,.$$
Now $u_n$ is a bounded sequence so $\lambda = \lim \sup u_n$ is finite, and we can find a subsequence $u_{n_j}$ that converges to $\lambda$. Since $X_n$ is aperiodic we know that $u_d > 0$ for all sufficiently large $d$, and along with null recurrence this implies $a_d > 0$ for all sufficiently large $d$. We prove that for such $d$, the sequence $u_{n_j-d}$ converges to the same limit $\lambda$.

---

Suppose the contrary is true. Then there exists some $\mu < \lambda$ such that $u_{n_j-d} < \mu$ for infinitely many $j$. Set $\varepsilon = a_d(\lambda-\mu)/3 > 0$. We have, by null recurrence,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 1 \quad \implies \quad \exists N \geq d\quad \text{with} \quad\sum_{n=1}^N a_n > 1 - \varepsilon \,.$$
Now let $j$ be such that $n_j \geq N$, $u_{n_j} > \lambda - \varepsilon$, $u_{n_j-d} < \mu$, and $u_n < \lambda + \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq n_j - N$. Then applying these inequalities to the recursion equation $(1)$ yields
$$ \begin{align}
u_{n_j} &<\sum_{k=0}^{n_j - N - 1} \,a_{n_j-k} + \sum_{k=n_j - N}^{n_j-1} u_k a_{n_j-k} < \varepsilon + \sum_{k=n_j - N}^{n_j-1}u_k \,a_{n_j-k} \\
&< \varepsilon + (\lambda + \varepsilon)(a_1 + \cdots a_{d-1} + a_{d+1} + \cdots + a_N) + a_d \mu \\
&<\varepsilon + (\lambda+ \varepsilon)(1- a_d) + a_d \mu <2 \varepsilon + \lambda - a_d(\lambda - \mu) = \lambda - \varepsilon \,.
\end{align}$$
But this contradicts $u_{n_j} > \lambda - \varepsilon$.

---

Now let $r_n = a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} + \cdots$, such that $r_0 = 1$ and $a_n = r_{n-1}-r_n$. By null recurrence we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n = \infty \tag{2} \,.$$
Then from equation $(1)$ we find
$$ r_0 u_n + r_1 u_{n-1} + \cdots + r_n u_0 = r_0 u_{n-1} + r_1 u_{n-2} + \cdots + r_{n-1} u_0 \,.$$
Setting the left hand side equal to $A_n$, this can be written
$A_n = A_{n-1}$, where $A_0 = r_0 u_0 = 1$. Hence for fixed $n_j \geq N \geq d$ we have
$$ r_{d} u_{n_j-d} + r_{d+1} u_{n_j-d-1}  + \cdots + r_{N} u_{n_j - N} \leq A_{n_j}= 1 \,. $$
Now taking the limit $j \to \infty$ leads to
$$ (r_d + r_{d+1} + \cdots +r_N) \lambda \leq 1 \,.$$
Finally, since $N$ is arbitrary, equation $(2)$ tells us $\lambda = 0$. Hence
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} u_n = 0 \,.$$

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but I wanted to say how the Karlin and Taylor proof can be seen as quite illuminating. The idea of looking at a "local limit" along $n_k$ is a general technique in ergodic theory. There is a way to do all the epsilon management up front that I think makes the proof clearer.

Given a sequence $n_k$, consider trying to define limiting local statistics $$p_{-d}=\lim_{\substack{k\to\infty\\ n_k\geq d}} p_{ii}^{(n_k-d)}\text{ for $d\geq 0$}$$
These limits might not converge for a general sequence $n_k$, but we can successively pass to smaller subsequences such that the limit for $d$ exists, and finally diagonalize to get a sequence where all the limits converge. In more detail: define $n^{0}_k=n_k$, and for each $d\geq 0$ pick a subsequence $n^{d+1}_k$ of $n^d_k$ such that $p_{ii}^{(n^{d+1}_k-d)}$ converges as $k\to\infty$. Then all the limits exist along the diagonal sequence $n^k_k$.

Even more abstractly, the limits can be conjured automatically from the Hahn-Banach theorem, or its other guises as the compactness theorem or ultrafilter lemma. This limit preserves some properties of the original sequences:

> **Lemma.**
>
> Consider a sequence of weights $w_d\geq 0$, $d\in\mathbb Z$, and assume that the limit $L=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{d=0}^{\infty} w_d p_{ii}^{(n_k-d)}$ exists. Then:
>
> - $\sum_{d=0}^\infty w_dp_{-d}\leq L$.
> - If $\sum_{d=0}^\infty w_d$ converges then $\sum_{d=0}^\infty w_dp_{-d}=L$.
>
> *Proof*. For each $N$ the sum $\sum_{d=0}^N w_d p_{ii}^{(n_k-d)}$ is a continuous function of the $N$-tuple $(p_{ii}^{(n_k-0)},\dots,p_{ii}^{(n_k-N)})$, and the lim sup is at most $L$, so the limit is at most $L$. For the second point, note that the error term $\sum_{d=N+1}^\infty w_d p_{ii}^{(n_k-d)}$ is at most $\sum_{d=N+1}^\infty w_d$, which tends to zero as $N\to\infty$.

The Karlin and Taylor argument can be put in this setting as follows. We can find a sequence $n_k$ giving limits satisfying $p_0=\lambda>0$ and $p_{-d}\leq\lambda$ for all $d$. Then, using the above lemma, and notation from your answer:

- $\sum_{d=0}^\infty r_d p_{-d}\leq 1$
- $\sum_{d=1}^\infty a_d p_{-d}=\lambda$
- $p_{-d}\leq \lambda$ for each $d$ (it's a limit of values with lim sup at most $\lambda$)

The condition $\sum_{d=1}^\infty a_d p_{-d}=\lambda$ is a convex combination of the values $p_{-d}\leq\lambda$, which forces $p_{-d}=\lambda$ whenever $a_d>0$. But $\{d\mid a_d>0\}$ has bounded gaps, which means $\lambda\sum_{d:a_d>0} r_d$ diverges, contradicting $\sum_{d=0}^\infty r_d p_{-d}\leq 1$.